# Are there zero entries in the eigenvector corresponding to a simple eigenvalue?

Tags: eigenvalues, matrix-theory, eigenvector

For a real symmetric matrix $M$ and a simple eigenvalue $\lambda$, under which conditions the corresponding eigenvector has no zero entries? Perhaps, this is unconditional and one can provide a proof?

Comment: Certainly no-$0$-entry-ness is not unconditional; consider a diagonal matrix with distinct entries.

Answer (score 2):

Any $n$ orthogonal vectors are eigenvectors of some symmetric matrix.

One example of a sufficient condition which implies that all coordinates of an eigenvector are non-zero is that the matrix has positive entries, and the eigenvector corresponds to the largest eigenvalue (Perron-Frobenus theorem). In this case, the eiegnvalue of largest absolute value is positive and simple, and the corresponding eigenvectors can be chosen to have all positive coordinates.

Comment: Thx to both of you. I am working on this, and at this moment it seems that the $(i, j)$-entry is non-zero iff the submatrix obtained by deleting the $i$th row and the $j$th column has no $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue.